# how to maintain scrollbar in razor page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

i making webProject.

I'm making a web on a razor page.

A page ->
B-page ->
Apage
I want to remember and keep the full scroll of page A when I return as above.
But the example I found was a razor view and its queryselector didn't work

page transition from A to B

```
 <a asp-page="./ViewBorad" asp-route-boradid="@Model.borad_tbl[i].tbl_Board.board_id"
```

My idea was to save it in tempdata and then call the data from onget.

```
 [BindProperty]
 public int ScrollPosition { get; set; }
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
   if (TempData["ScrollPosition"] != null)
                ScrollPosition = (int)TempData["ScrollPosition"];
}
```

1. how to save scrollbar value in asp-page part in bind property
2. how to access BindProperty in js part

how I thought

1. When switching from page A to page B, call js and store the current scrollbar position in cookie
   When you load page A again after doing so, if there is a cookie, it goes to that location.

Problem) I don't know how to get the corresponding value in js and throw the corresponding scroll value to c# bindproperty access the cookie in js

2. Utilizing Back When you use Back, the page's scroll bar is automatically remembered.

Problem) When a button that calls a function in C# is pressed, the page is reloaded.
If you use href='javascript:history.go(-1)', the reloading behavior is skipped

```
 <input asp-page-handler="ChangeComplete" asp class="btn" type="submit" value="OK" style=" background-color: white;
                 float: right ; margin-left: 6px; "
              href='javascript:history.go(-1)'/>
```

Comment: If you want to access `ScrollPosition` in js,you can try to use `@ScrollPosition`.

Comment: @YiyiYou how to access fullwindow scrollbar? `ScrollPosition` keyword is not founded